# UIBarButtonItem unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

I have laid out the buttons in Interface Builder and connected them as outlets

```
  @IBOutlet weak var outletCatalogDetailsToolBarLink: UIBarButtonItem!
```

In `viewDidLoad` I have this:

```
outletCatalogDetailsToolBarLink.target = self;
outletCatalogDetailsToolBarLink.action = Selector("OwnHandleButtonClick");
```

The handler is defined like this:

```
  func OwnHandleButtonClick(Sender: AnyObject) -> Void {
```

However, when the button is clicked I get an error chain starting with:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

All answers I see online have the buttons created at runtime. While that is of course a solution, I would like to understand how to code against controls placed design time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of about 5000 existing Stack Overflow questions. Please do make an effort to search before asking.

Comment: @matt - the 15+ SOs I found creates the buttons runtime which then gets accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
outletCatalogDetailsToolBarLink.action = Selector("OwnHandleButtonClick:")
```

Mind the `:`.

Also, Swift doesn't require semicolons `;` at the end of each line.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! I actually traversed dozens of SO answers trying to figure out how to do it since it seems most just create buttons runtime. I still find the concept a little bewildering why I can not assign methods directly through some other mechanism, but using strings will work fine with the scale of my projects.

Comment: @Tom You have not understood the significance of this answer. The significance is that the name of `func OwnHandleButtonClick(Sender: AnyObject)` as a selector is _not_ `"OwnHandleButtonClick"`, which is what you had. It is `"OwnHandleButtonClick:"` with a colon. This has _nothing to do with how the button is created_.

Comment: @matt I can find multiple SOs (including accepted) answers that propose UIBarButtonItem(.... action: Selector("string")) and UIBarButtonItem(.... action: "string") where the string does not contain ":" and it is true, as I stated that in the original Q that answer was not what I wanted. I *did* see the ":" in Daniels answer since Daniel specificly highlighted it... So yes, I tried adding colon, and as I wrote, it worked with the colon. But yes, you are correct that Daniel besides showing how to solve the problem -without- creating buttons runtime also showed me that I needed to use the colon.